# How to determine what is intercepting mailto: links and disable the interception to have the default Apple Mail handle the mailto: links

Tags: email, web-browser

At some point way back in the past, I set up some utility to intercept mailto: links in web pages and have Chrome compose a message in Gmail rather than having it open the Apple Mail app.

Now, I'm trying to remove it and have Apple Mail open mailto: links, but I can't figure out the utility I used to intercept them.

I thought it might have been [Webmailer](http://belkadan.com/webmailer/readme), but I checked System Preferences, and it's not in there. Also, I looked in my Chrome and Safari extensions, and no extensions that are currently installed have anything to do with redirecting mailto: links. Though it may have been a browser extension I installed and later removed.

I'm on Mac OS 10.7.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy and paste `chrome://settings/handlers` into the address bar in Chrome and check for an active protocol handler for Gmail.

If you don't find something there, you could try installing [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) which should list any system wide protocol handlers.

Comment: Thanks. The Chrome approach didn't do it for me. I copied `chrome://settings/handlers` into Chrome. I found an active protocol handler that read "type" = "mailto"; "site" = "Gmail". I removed it, and it no longer shows up there. Quit Chrome and restarted it a couple of times, restarted Mac OS, and still when I clicked a "mailto:" link, it opened Chrome. 

However, [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) worked like a charm.